# Setting a Sprite to another Sprite in assets folder in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to be able to change the score of the game using images I have. The images are of numbers 0-9. However my artist did not pack them into one texture so I must call them one by one. I tried doing it like so:

```
rOnes = GameObject.Find("EnhancedTextHandler/Ones").GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();
rTens = GameObject.Find("EnhancedTextHandler/Tens").GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();
rHuns = GameObject.Find("EnhancedTextHandler/Hundreds").GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();

rOnes.sprite = Resources.Load<Sprite>("Pong/Numbers/1black");
```

This was just to test if I can set the sprite to a new sprite. However I get the following error:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'Sprite' to 'UnityEngine.Sprite'

I can't find any documentation on the difference between `Sprite` and `UnityEngine.Sprite`.

How can I assign a Sprite from a SpriteRenderer a new Sprite?

I don't want to make a ton of references to the Sprites like this:

```
Sprite ref1, ref2, ref3, ref4, etc;
rOnes.sprite = ref1;
```

But even so I get the same error.

Comment: What is `rOnes` defined as? You left that part off and is your error from the `rOnes.sprite = Resources.Load<Sprite>("Pong/Numbers/1black");` line?

Comment: It is at the top it is a SpriteRenderer @Programmer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot implicitly convert  type Sprite to UnityEngine.Sprite , so try converting it explicitly stating it

```
greenSprite = Resources.Load ("SpritesFolderName/" + "mySpritename", typeof(Sprite)) as Sprite;
```